# Magento 2 - extend Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.js

Tags: magento2

I need to add custom validation rule to postcode field in my checkout page. Therefore I need to extend `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.js` file.

How can I achieve it in custom module (not theme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override inside your module using below way,
**app/code/Krish/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules": "Krish_Checkout/js/lib/validation/rules"
        }
    }
};
```

Create js file at 
**app/code/Krish/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js**

Run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command.

Comment: Will this same work for magento2.3.3/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/da_DK/Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules.js

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override the whole rules file you can extend post-code component

1. Change postal-code component in `Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         layout="checkout"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
   >
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
               <arguments>
                   <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                   <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                           <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                   <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code-custom</item>
                                                                       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                           <item name="validate-postal-custom" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                       </item>
                                                                   </item>
                                                               </item>
                                                           </item>
                                                       </item>
                                                   </item>
                                               </item>
                                           </item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </argument>
               </arguments>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
2. Create the new component `Magento_Ui/web/js/form/element/post-code-custom.js` and add the new validation rule:

   ```
   define([
       'jquery',
       'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
       'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code'
   ], function($, validator, Element) {
       'use strict';

       return Element.extend({
           initialize: function() {

               validator.addRule(
                   'validate-postal-custom',
                   function(value) {
                       // validation logic
                       return true or false;
                   },
                   $.mage.__('Please specify a valid postal code')
               );

               this._super();
           }
       });
   });
   ```